# vs buildtools container 'dotnet test' unable to find tests for Dotnet Core test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, mstest

I have a dotnet core test project using mstest and targeting framework 461 with runtime identifier of win7-x64 but it cannot locate the tests when the 'dotnet test' command is run.

Returning error: No test is available in . Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are app

I am using the vsbuildtools2017 container from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container to perform the action.

csproj propertyGroup settings:

```
<PropertyGroup> <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework> <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier> </PropertyGroup>
```

csproj packages:

```
<ItemGroup> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.7.0" /> <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.2.1" /> <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.2.1" />
```

I have also tried using the vstest.console.exe and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `dotnet test` on the root folder will work **IF** you have the code project and the test project following the naming convention: `<name>.csproj` and `<name>.Tests.csproj`.

Another approach is to provide the path on the command like so:

```
dotnet test path/to/foo.tests.csproj
```

This will also work with multiple projects, just separate the arguments with a space.

Here is an Example using xUnit:

- https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/getting-started/unit-testing-using-dotnet-test